# Open a .Bat Using Java Apllication

Tags: cmd

I'm trying to Open the CMD Using java + Applying code to it to open an .jar so the applications output is shown in the .bat file.
can someone tell me how to do it?

This is the code it got,it does run excecute the file but the CMD doesnt show.

```
btnTest.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            String Bat = "C:"+File.separatorChar+"Users"+File.separatorChar+"Gebruiker"+File.separatorChar+"AppData"+File.separatorChar+"Local"+File.separatorChar+"Temp"+File.separatorChar+"hexT"+File.separatorChar+"run.bat";
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            try {
                rt.exec(Bat);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Show us your code and explain what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: What does "output is shown in the .bat file" mean?

Comment: it runs an .jar wich has output like debug stuff, when i run the .bat file manualy it does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited: This works for me:

```
String Bat = "C:\\app.bat";  //Try to use \\ as path seperator

try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start " + Bat);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: it does load the application and the .bat file, but im still not getting the output.

Comment: Was tempOutFile.txt created?

Comment: Yea it works for me aswell but i need the consult to keep running it now closes on when the executed once.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understant your question. To keep what running? What closes when what executed once?

Comment: The .bat file stops operating when the .jar loads, but it should stay active to get the output from the .jar file.

Comment: Please show me the code of the batch file, because I think the problem is in the batch, not in the Java code, because Java can't do much more than starting the batch. - What happens afterwards depends on the batch-code.

Answer (score 0):

Define this :

```
FileWriter writer;
```

then in your try/catch do the following :

```
    try {
        writer = new FileWriter("test.txt");
        Process child = rt.exec(Bat);
        InputStream input = child.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(input);
        BufferedReader commandResult = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(buffer));
        String line = "";
        try {
            while ((line = commandResult.readLine()) != null) {
         writer.write(line + "\n");              
            }
        writer.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This will read the output as a buffer line by line and write it into a text file